# cannot convert parameter 1 from 'CStringListX *__w64 ' to 'CStringListX &'

Tags: c++

I am making a wrapper for a Cpp DLL, but am getting trouble with the following function:

```
void PyGetUSBDeviceNames(DFUEngine *DFUe, CStringListX &devices)
{
    return DFUe->GetUSBDeviceNames(&devices);
}
```

I get the error:
 error C2664: 'DFUEngine::GetUSBDeviceNames' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'CStringListX *__w64 ' to 'CStringListX &'

The function GetUSBDeviceNames is defined in the h file as:

```
static int GetUSBDeviceNames(CStringListX &devices);
```

how can I get around this one?
Thanks alot

Comment: Why are you returning an int when the signature is void?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the unneeded &:

```
return DFUe->GetUSBDeviceNames(devices);
```